# Unable to use keyboard controls when playing XCOM 2 offline

Tags: steam, xcom-2

Tested this three times, found the same result each time. After Steam goes offline and you attempt to play XCOM 2, keyboards dont work whatsoever. I can't use Q & E to rotate, use TAB to switch between soldiers, and right click does nothing, so I cannot move soldiers. I can't hit ESC to load a save, and I can't change elevation.

Anyone else getting this exact issue when Steam is offline? And if so, how did you fix it?

To clarify, this occurs regardless if:

- Steam is in Offline Mode
- Steam is in Online mode (but has lost internet connection)

And the game is running pure vanilla, with no mods.

Comment: O_o Weeeeeiiiird

Comment: Do you have a controller plugged in by any chance? Figure it might have something to do with it, otherwise it is very weird indeed.

Comment: This is totally strange.  I'd check USB devices and make sure there isn't something odd there.  Otherwise, what mods (if any) are you using?

Comment: @Kikanaide It's pure vanilla XCOM 2, no mods. Re-edited the question

Comment: @skully then I can't help you, sorry.  Best of luck!

Comment: After the first 'offline no multiplayer' message, there is a second message about 10 seconds later saying that 2k stuff also isn't available. Need to wait for and acknowledge the extra message.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason it is happening is because you are not waiting for the "Cannot connect" message to pop up.
I found that if you run the game and just load up your saved game, your keyboard stops responding. the only keys that work is your numbers. also you cannot move anywhere.
BUT
if you run the game, get to the menu and wait until the game gives you the cannot connect to the server message, then load your game, everything works 100%